# Find usages of task groups

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have quite a lot build and release pipelines and we are using task groups frequently. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a possibility to find the pipelines that use a certain task group.

Is there any way to find all usages of a task group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taskgroup has a "References"-tab that shows where it is beeing used.[image]

Comment: OMG, I'm so blind:-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @D.J. This has already been withdrawn, has it not?

Comment: @kki dont know what you mean, that part of devops and the answer are still up to date and look the same in the current version even after almost 5 years